# Как получить все допустимые разрешения экрана и переключаться между ними?

Tags: c#, wpf

Решил попрактиковаться в написании игр на WPF. Столкнулся с необходимостью изменять разрешение экрана программно. Но к сожалению все что смог найти написано под WinForms. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать, или возможно есть готовые библиотеки?

Comment: Вызов Win API функций работает в формах и WPF одинаково. А вообще разрешение экрана менять нельзя, если у меня монитор 1920x1080 и у него стоит родное разрешение - это значит оно лучшее. На какое разрешение вы хотите поменять и почему?

Comment: @aepot, в настройках почти всех игр есть опция изменения разрешения, и я провозился уже больше часа, но к сожалению не нашел то что бы мне помогло на тему Win API. Возможно вы правы, и на данный момент стоит отказаться от идеи изменения разрешения.

Comment: На полном экране вам нужно под разрешение подстраиваться, а не разрешение под себя. Прошли уже те времена с ламповыми мониками, где 150 разрешений поддерживалось. Сейчас на LCD мониторах одно единственное разрешение поддерживается, его и используйте. Все остальные настройки в оконном режиме пусть меняют только размер окна.

Comment: это нужно в основном для оптимизации, допустим при полном разрешении у кого-то тормозит, то можно его уменьшить. Но то что у меня вряд-ли будет лагать, так что пока оставлю эту затею.

Comment: Кто не может играть на разрешении монитора - играет в окне (но случай действительно редкий, вы же не Киберпанк тормозящий там написали), а там хоть за уголок размер меняй, хоть в настройках выставляй. В полном экране актуален только родной размер монитора, в противном случае пиксель размоется и графон будет не четкий. Особенно хреново будет смотреться размыленный интерфейс с кнопками и менюшками - никто не захочет в такое играть. К счастью, времена, когда можно было за счет снижения разрешения получить небольшой прирост FPS, уже прошли.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли